# Поиск максимального значения при условиях

Tags: excel

Делаю в *Excel* протокол для соревнований, там присутствую такие поля:

> `1 подход| 2 подход| 3 подход`

Под каждым подходом `2` ячейки: в первой указывается вес, во второй ставится `X` в случае неудачного подхода.

В ячейку *Результат* нужно выводить наибольший вес, правее которого не присутствует `X`
пока удалось только сделать так

```
=ЕСЛИ(J13="";I13;ЕСЛИ(L13="";K13;ЕСЛИ(N13="";M13;)))
```

Работает, но не так, как нужно.
Прошу помощи
[image: Скрин]

Comment: понимаю что нужно написать примерно так J13="" то выводим I13 если L13="" то выводим K13 если N13="" то выводим M13, а вот как ко всему этому применить Больше, меньше....

Answer (score 0):

Добрый вечер!

Попробуйте следующую формулу:

```
=МАКС(ЕСЛИ(J13<>"X";I13;0);ЕСЛИ(L13<>"X";K13;0);ЕСЛИ(N13<>"X";M13;0))
```

Только учтите, что русское "Х" и английское "X" - это разные буквы, и результат будет разный в зависимости от того, что вы введёте. Чтобы избежать ошибки можно расширить формулу до:

```
=МАКС(ЕСЛИ(И(J13<>"Х";J13<>"X");I13;0);ЕСЛИ(И(L13<>"Х";L13<>"X");K13;0);ЕСЛИ(И(N13<>"Х";N13<>"X");M13;0))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) Вы меня спасли от бессонной ночи)

Answer (score 0):

Если неудачный подход, то и значение не пишется, только "*Х*"?

В этом случае достаточно:

```
=МАКС(I13:M13)
```

Если же при наличии буквы может быть вписано и значение:

```
=МАКС(ЕСЛИ(J13="";I13);ЕСЛИ(L13="";K13);ЕСЛИ(N13="";M13))
```

То же (короче, но вычислений больше):

```
=МАКС(I13*(J13="");K13*(L13="");M13*(N13=""))
```

Для разнообразия - формула массива:

```
=МАКС(ЕСЛИ(J13:N13="";I13:M13))
```

Ввод формулы завершается нажаием трех клавиш (*Ctrl+Shift+Enter*), должна обрамиться фигурными скобками. Эта формула, кроме ввода как формулы массива,  имеет еще один недостаток - выполняет больше вычислений по сравнению с формулами, показанноыми выше.